# how to not improve this code to not repeat the twitter bootstrap modal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a `Project` that have many `Pictures`. I am using the first picture as a link to call a [twitter bootstrap modal](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals), where some information will be displayed as well as the link for the project`s page.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="<%= project.id %>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3><%= project.title %> <small><%= project.sub_title %></small></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p><%= ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize (project.description) %></p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <%= link_to 'More Details', project_path(project), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

In order to get the modal working for each project, I have added the `project.id` to the `Modal id`. So, I am actually creating many modals, one for each project.

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <%= link_to (image_tag project.pictures.first.url), "##{project.id}", class: 'btn', role: 'button', data: { toggle: 'modal' } %>
  <%= render 'projects/modal', project: project %>
<% end %>
```

Well, everything is working fine, but I don't like it! It will became a loading problem if I have many projects.

So, I would like to find a way to not load all modals. I would like to have one modal template that is populated by the project information.

Any idea on how to improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*NOTE:* I don't have rails set up at the moment, so can't test this directly, but should work:

Put the following generic modal code into the modal partial:

```
<div id="genericModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <%= link_to 'More Details', nil, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Include the following at the top of your view:

```
<script>
function populateModal(projectId) {
     $(".modal-header").find("h3").html($(projectId).find("#p_title").html());
     $(".modal-body").find("p").html($(projectId).find("#p_desc").html());
     $(".modal-footer").find("a").attr("href", $(projectId).find("#p_link > a").attr("href"));
     $("#genericModal").modal('show');
}
</script>
```

Then further down in your view, you can do something like this:

```
<%= render 'projects/modal' %>
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <%= link_to (image_tag project.pictures.first.url), html => {:onclick => "populateModal('##{project.id}')", :class => 'btn', :role => 'button'} %>
  <div id="#{project.id}" class="hide">
    <span id="p_title"><%= project.title %> <small><%= project.sub_title %><small></span>
    <span id="p_desc"><%= ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize (project.description) %></span>
    <span id="p_link"><%= link_to project_path(project) %></span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a single modal, not one for each project. Use javascript to open the modal on each link (instead of `data-toggle="modal"`) and before you do, set the project's title, subtitle, description and link using Javascript.